# How to add package to SVN Working Copy in Xcode 4.3.2 Organizer?

Tags: iphone, xcode, svn

I renamed my project,  Xcode created a new package, and the old one is left there also.
The application works fine with the new name, but when I want to commit to SVN, i have an error like a file from the new package is marked as "copied", but not scheduled for addition or inside an unversioned directory.
When I want to add to SVN in console, I have a warning about it is already under version control.

The problem is: I can see only the old package in the organizer, it is marked as deleted, but I can not see the new one.

How can I add it to the list?

Answer (score 0):

Get a fresh copy from the repository and then bring back your modifications from the renamed folder (excluding the.svn ones).

When finished delete the renamed folder. Otherwise you might end up with broken folders:

```
If you renaming a project, Xcode does not remove the .svn directory in the .xcodeproj. As a result, svn gets confused, thinking the renamed project directory is under version control
```